# Isn't the BBC being extremely irresponsible in describing how to authenticate an account-related email?

Tags: email, phishing

On [this webpage](http://www.bbc.co.uk/faqs/bbc_account_email), the BBC says:

> #### I’ve received a ‘Changes to your BBC account’ email claiming to be from the BBC – is this a genuine email?
>
> At the end of September 2016, we upgraded our ‘BBC iD’ sign-in system to ‘BBC Account’, and as a result we had to sign everyone out of their ‘BBC iD’ account.
>
> If an email address was previously registered against a ‘BBC iD’ account, we’ve been sending emails to these email addresses (from ‘bbcaccount@e.bbcmail.co.uk’) advising users that we’ve signed them out of their account and asking them to sign back in.
>
> These are genuine emails from the BBC and not phishing emails or spam (below is a screenshot of the email content).

… and that's it.

I discovered this on a Facebook comment thread, where the above webpage was given as "proof" that an unexpected email was genuine and not a phish.

The email contains a link to "sign in" — this link will require users to input their credentials, by definition (due to the reason for sending the email in the first place).

Isn't all of this incredibly irresponsible? Isn't the BBC grossly mistraining its audience? The *From* field of an email has never been anywhere close to proof of the sender's identity, and providing a screenshot of the genuine content just makes it easier for fraudsters to reproduce it and con people.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: How can we be sure that that page is legitimate? ;) On the other hand, BBC already redirects away from HTTPS, so they're not exactly security savvy.

Comment: @Rhymoid It really does not use HTTPS. Incredible in this day and age.

Comment: @Rhymoid HTTPS is supported on the home page, and on all http://bbc.com pages. I am going to guess that the reasons for this are legacy support. They're running two domains (bbc.co.uk and bbc.com) here, as well as the archives - news.bbc.co.uk as well as others. http://news.bbc.co.uk pages don't even allow HTTPS - they just don't load.

Comment: @Rhymoid however, I did decide to contact them - with this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8Aur.png

Comment: @Tim For a second, I thought you wew going to contact them with [this](https://i.imgur.com/qwYQN6j.jpg), because this all seems very backwards to me.

Comment: Well what else should they do to tell people the site closed... make a redirect link?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: No site closed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "At the end of September 2016, we upgraded our ‘BBC iD’ sign-in system to ‘BBC Account’, and as a result we had to sign everyone out of their ‘BBC iD’ account." If the site didn't change then what's the big deal? You got a notification. Just relog into the site directly without clicking links in the email...

Comment: @TheGreatDuck now if you can just give that advice to everyone who got the email then problem solved

Comment: @rdans you mean the email didn't tell people to just go to the site through their web browser and not click any links in the email?

Comment: What I want to know is why they didn't just log people out and assume people will figure it out themselves later...?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: The site changed. It did not close. _"Then what's the big deal?"_ Well, exactly. They shouldn't have provided a link in the email, because they didn't need to. And furthermore they shouldn't have insinuated that using such a link is safe just because an email appears to come from a BBC address. An unusual BBC domain, at that, so there are multiple layers of mistraining here!

Comment: @Tim Please don't lead the witness

Comment: @Michael Hu????

Comment: @Tim I wouldn't offer them any information on my suspicions - at best it's going to be ignored, and at worst it gives them an out to just agree with you.

Comment: @Michael I doubt that is going to change their response. It's likely the correct answer. Let's see.

Comment: I'd like to add that I just received this email and it was automatically tagged as spam in Google Mail. So even the algorithms seem to agree that this is terrible security practice.

Comment: @Tim They've fixed it now; HTTPS support across the board.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

*Very* dangerous things could happen here, indeed. It would be laughably easy for a scammer to phish users.

A migration is an excuse many phishers *already* use:

> There was xyz problem in our user database [...] just "log in" or you won't be
>   able to use our service.

So the legitimate reason

> we upgraded our ‘BBC iD’ sign-in system to ‘BBC Account’

aligns quite perfectly with these nefarious activities. Spammers could even put a "proof" with the website link. Users see that the email layout is the same, think *oh, this is legit*, click sign-in and send the credentials to the attackers.

Having access to a BBC account isn't much of a threat, as far as I know. However, for those users who have the same password in all sites (and no two-step verification), then you've got an easy way to access email, bank accounts, and the like.

The BBC dropped the ball ***hard***. I'll be contacting them to fix the issue, I encourage you to do the same thing.

Comment: It may be true that the BBC Account may not have much of value worth protecting.  Even so the real damage here is perpetuating the idea that emails like this are ever legit.  In addition there is nothing here that couldn't be communicated more effectively and timely when users visit the site. Which leaves me feeling like this email is mostly meant to remind you to visit the site.  It's actually genuine spam.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Enough people re-use passwords that the password itself is probably orders of magnitude more valuable than the BBC Account.

Comment: They should write on the very same page to check for duplicate e-mails, since everyone concerned gets a one legitimate one.

Comment: Also: "please re-register, giving us your postcode, as despite numerous claims of Culture-level technology being created to find out if you have a TV License when using iPlayer, in fact the only real way is to try to match your BBC Account postcode to a registered License postcode."

Comment: Not much of a threat?  My BBC account got hacked, and now my TARDIS has been stolen!

Comment: Whenever I see an email like that that I confirm is fake, I don't send my credentials. I type in as many fake credentials as I can think of. Sometimes I even type in as a password "Did you really think that would work?".

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: With that, you're potentially just letting them know that your email address is valid and connects to a person... which, a lot of the time, is all they wanted to know in the first place. Don't engage at all.